# MessagingCentre Does it pass object by value or by reference?

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

With reference to [.Net Maui: How to read/write (get/set) a global object from any content page (MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913742/net-maui-how-to-read-write-get-set-a-global-object-from-any-content-page-mv)

I now have a need to pass an object that is rather a large (>500Mb), it is an OpenMap extract, a RouterDb object (Itinero http://docs.itinero.tech/index.html)

Though I am trying to use MVVM some packages (Mapsui) use code behind so I am left with a mixture of ViewModel and Codebehind. I can overcome the limitation of not having any kind of global object reference by using the MessagingCenter which works remarkably well.

I am wondering if this mechanism can handle the passing of large objects (megabytes) or if internally it simply passes a reference to the object. I suspect from my experiments that it is trying to pass a copy of the object and failing, as I end up with a null object.

Here's the code
MessagingMarker.cs - just a placeholder class

```
namespace RouteIt.Models;

public class MessagingMarker
{
}
```

In my MainPageViewModel.cs

```
    //Takes about 10seconds to load
    using (var stream = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\Resources\Raw\gb.routerdb").OpenRead())
    {
      routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    //send message to codebehind containing object or reference?
    MessagingCenter.Send(new MessagingMarker(), "RouterDbLoaded", routerDb);
```

and in my receiving MainPage.xaml.cs constructor

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessagingMarker, RouterDb>(this, "RouterDbLoaded", (sender, arg) =>
    {
      routerDb = arg;
    });

  router = new(routerDb);
```

Any thoughts? (And yes perhaps I need to re-struture my app, but at this stage I don't want to really, one day Mapsui might support mvvm apparently.)

As always thanks for at least reading :)

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but a general work-around (both for message-passing, and for AppShell query parameters) is to have a globally accessible `Dictionary` (on your app class, or as a static on any widely-accessed class), and put that object into that global dictionary, with an id that doesn't change. Then you pass around the id. An ancient programming practice, but it works. If concerned about holding on to object too long (memory leak), then make a "weak reference" wrapper object, to put in dictionary.  I define static helper methods with `<T>` to simplify typed access.

Comment: I like it. :)  I've now got the messaging to work and I don't notice any degradation in performance certainly not a 10 second wait. I did notice that I couldn't send a message from the ViewModel constructor or any sub function.

Comment: AFAIK, should be possible to send messages from anywhere.